# Bootstrap navbar does works when in full screen but not when condensed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Currently, my navbar in bootstrap looks fine when in full screen. It looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2D7X.png).

However, bootstrap automatically condense the items in to a stack when below a certain width. That is when it looks bad as the Register and Login are on the same line. Looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaRdU.png).

I want the navbar to have the Register and Login routes on the right while containing the routes as a stack when condensed.

Current HTML for the nav.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('home')}}">Test</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
        {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
            <span class="navbar-text mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <a href="{{ url_for('logout')}}" class="me-4">Logout</a>
            </span>
        {% else%}
            <span class="navbar-text mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <a href="{{ url_for('login')}}" class="me-4">Login</a>
            </span>
            <span class="navbar-text mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <a href="{{ url_for('register')}}" class="me-4">Register</a>
            </span>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not sure if I understand the question pretty well,
but from what I understand I would move the login, register, and logoff into a div and apply a media query in the CSS to do what you ask for.

```
<style>
 @media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
   .chnageMeWhenSmall {
    position: absolute;
    right: 60px;
    }
  }
</style>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('home')}}">Test</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
  <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Pricing</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
     <div class="chnageMeWhenSmall">
    {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
        <span class="navbar-text mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <a href="{{ url_for('logout')}}" class="me-4">Logout</a>
        </span>
    {% else%}
        <span class="navbar-text mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <a href="{{ url_for('login')}}" class="me-4">Login</a>
        </span>
        <span class="navbar-text mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <a href="{{ url_for('register')}}" class="me-4">Register</a>
        </span>
    {% endif %}
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/Superawdi/pen/GROeeYJ

Comment: That's one way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Navbar should appear as a stack only in mobile view. You can also consider checking if you have added xs- classes properly to get the desired view. I can only see lg classes in your snippet. Pelase try to share the codepen if it still doesn't work.